# How to create shortcut to specific phone settings from my app?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8

I want an shortcut from my app, when I click on the icon, user will navigate to setting page (Start + theme, Wifi, sound, etc...)

I've seen this in many app (one click to wifi, bluetooth, cellular...) So there's def somehow I can achieve this. I'm using SDK 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are Windows-Phone Tasks available for certain Settings you listed

Example for WIFI:

```
var page = new Microsoft.Phone.Tasks.ConnectionSettingsTask();
page.ConnectionSettingsType = Microsoft.Phone.Tasks.ConnectionSettingsType.WiFi;
page.Show();
```

complete reference can be found here:

[ConnectionSettingsType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.tasks.connectionsettingstype)